# laravel form posting to new route

Tags: php, laravel

I'm starting from the blade password.blade.php which is loaded from the route

```
Route::get('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@getEmail')
->name('auth.password.email');
```

In the blade I have a form that I'm trying to post to the route:

```
Route::post('password/change', 'User\UserController@password')
->name('user.password.change');
```

Like so:

```
{!! Form::open(array('method' => 'POST', 'url' => route('user.password.change'))) !!}
     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="email">Email Address</label>
         <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Send Email</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

However, it seems like it's still posting to the 'password/email' route that gets the starting blade, if that makes sense.

How can I make sure that it posts to the user.password.change route?

Comment: Look in the html source.

Comment: When I do inspect it, the form action shows the POST action to the correct route though

Comment: Add and dd() on UserController@password

Comment: Well so your question got an answer

Comment: @JoaoGRRR Ok I added that and it looks like it's not hitting that function. So, I had an issue before with another page but I have a form on another page posting the exact same way to that route/function. I figured it has something to do with the current route that this form is on

Comment: Form::open(array('method' => 'POST', 'url' =>'user.password.change')) !!}

You may also open forms that point to named routes or controller actions

Comment: @dparoli So if the source does indeed show the correct url in the post action, but it's not hitting that for some reason (even though another page hits it just fine) what would that imply? If it helps, the other page that successfully hits user.password.change is a blade that comes from a route in the user space, but this current blade is in the auth space

Comment: I only said that your question is answered, and it is. Now why it does not show the correct page is another question and from the code you posted is difficult to to guess why your target page does not show up.

Comment: What's happening at the UserController? Are you using any Request validation rules that your current request does not satisfy?

Comment: @BharatGeleda yes I'm checking the request for the email so that it would fail with no email address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### route() must not be returning a URL

If you're not posting to the correct route, then route must be returning false or null.  This would imply that you're not passing all the parameters necessary, or that there is a problem with the route in question.  The question becomes, "Why?"

#### Routes Cache

One possibility is that the route cache needs to be updated.  This can be done with the artisan command:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

#### Expected Passing User

The routes in the Question make it seems like this isn't the case, but if your UsersController function requires a User $user, you need to make sure your routes and form reflect that.

Assuming you're using an older version of Laravel or the Laravel collective.  The issue is in your [form open](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#opening-a-form).  You're not passing in the user for which you want to change the password, if your using Auth::user() you might not need to pass that parameter  (Also, make sure the route checks that you're not changing the password on another account)

```
{!! Form::open(array('method' => 'POST', 'route' => ['user.password.change,'user'=>$user->id]])) !!}
```

OR

```
{!! Form::open(array('method' => 'POST', 'url' => 'user/' . $user->id . 'password/change'])) !!}
```

### Avoid the Whole Mess

Also, unless you have a strong reason not to, you shouldn't need to make your own routes for authentication. Laravel has an [auth package available](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) you can add to any project that is running Laravel 5.4+.

Comment: I suppose that the $id parameter is not needed  because from the route code above is not defined and, usually, the password change function is for the current authenticated user.

Comment: Hmmm...  Right but route doesn't sound like it is returning a url.  But the routes the OP posted mean you might be correct.  I don't know why they are insisting on writing their own auth stuff for stuff that exists -- unless they are using an older version or Laravel that doesn't have Auth.

Comment: I agree with you and seeing the effort you put on correctly answering a so obscure question you deserve an upvote.

Comment: @J.A.Streich Thank you, this at least helps to shed some light. We are using 5.2 and have been using the built in auth package but we are now using AWS and JWT to move user data out of the database which means I'm now using an AWS endpoint to reset passwords, which is why I'm using this method